# Pass Static Select Option Value to Laravel Controller using AJAX/Axios

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to call select option value into laravel condition and I want to know how to using it in my `create.blade.php`, here is the example:

```
@if (a is selected)
   // code goes here
@endif
```

`a` is select option value

Currently, I'm using ajax to convert html value into php value but still not working.
How do I pass it?

---

Here's my select option code in `create.blade.php`

```
<div class="form-group">
   <p class="card-text">Jenis Jadwal </p>
   <div class="">
      <select class="form-control" id="frm-status" name="status">
         <option value="">PIlih</option>
         <option value="rutin" {{ old('status') == 'rutin' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Rutin</option>
         <option value="khusus" {{ old('status') == 'khusus' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Khusus</option>
         <option value="libur-tahunan" {{ old('status') == 'libur-tahunan' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Libur Tahunan</option>
         <option value="nge-plus" {{ old('status') == 'nge-plus' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Nge-plus</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's my ajax script in `create.blade.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(function() {

                $('#colorpicker').farbtastic('#warna');

                // run on change for the selectbox
                $( "#frm-status" ).change(function() {
                    updateStatusDivs();
                });

                // handle the updating of the duration divs
                function updateStatusDivs() {
                    // hide all form-duration-divs
                    $('.form-status-div').hide();

                    var divKey = $( "#frm-status option:selected" ).val();
                    var getStatus = null;
                    $('#divFrm'+divKey).show();

                    if (divKey === "khusus") {
                        $('#divFrmtanggal').show();
                        $('#divFrmjadwal').show();
                        $('#divFrmcheckbox').hide();
                        getStatus = "khusus"
                    } else if (divKey === "nge-plus"){
                        $('#divFrmtanggal').show();
                        $('#divFrmcheckbox').show();
                        getStatus = "nge-plus"
                    } else if (divKey === "libur-tahunan"){
                        $('#divFrmtanggal').show();
                        $('#divFrmcheckbox').show();
                        getStatus = "libur-tahunan"
                    } else if (divKey === "rutin"){
                        getStatus = "rutin"
                    };

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/jadwal/tablekaryawanajax',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            name: getStatus
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            console.log('error');
                        }
                    });
                };

                // run at load, for the currently selected div to show up
                updateStatusDivs();

            });
</script>
```

Here's my route for `tablekaryawanajax` (other routes in this group doesn't matter so I exclude them)

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'jadwal'], function () {
   Route::post('tablekaryawanajax', 'JadwalController@tablekaryawanajax')->name('jadwal.tablekaryawanajax');
});
```

Here's my `tablekaryawanajax` function in `JadwalController.php`

```
public function tablekaryawanajax(Request $request)
{
   return view('Jadwal.karyawantable', compact('karyawan'));
}
```

Comment: You get the status after the ajax response. So you can't do that with server-side language. Ajax will called after the process of backend. You need to to do that with javascript, not with php

Comment: I got your point, but do you have any idea how to fix them? load select option before I load create blade maybe?

Comment: Yes, pass the variable with your controller then selected the field with php variable